# Why is this kind of Borrow not allowed?

Tags: rust

I am a Rust newbie, struggling with *why* the compiler is strict here on ownership. Code simplified to focus on the confusion.

```
fn some_fn() {
    let mut a_map: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();

    loop {
        match create_area(&a_map) {
            -- pattern matching --
        }

        // This is the problem.
        a_map.clear();
    }
}

fn create_area(a_map: &HashMap<String, String>) -> Result {}
```

Error reads: "cannot borrow `a_map` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable"

My intuition is that because I am not changing owners of `a_map`, and that `create_area` cannot change `a_map` since the reference it has is immutable, it should be "safe" to mutate using `a_map.clear()`.

Altered the code to the following to get it to compile using clone, is there another way? Considering the case where a_map might be very large.

```
fn some_fn() {
    let mut a_map: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();

    loop {
        match create_area(a_map.clone()) {
            -- pattern matching --
        }

        a_map.clear();
    }
}

fn create_area(a_map: HashMap<String, String>) -> Result {}
```

Comment: You can either make many immutable borrows or you can make a single mutable borrow.

Comment: You should post the full code of the `match` statement.

Comment: Complementing @Justalearner's comment, use https://play.rust-lang.org to have / achieve a case which actually and fully reproduces the issue you're having, then post the code & a link to the playground. That gives would-be helper much better and more relevant information. And when you have a compilation error, the actual and entire error should also be posted.

Comment: You can certainly mutate the map, provided you don't leave immutable references lingering after the match. This is why it's important to show us what you do inside `match`, because it's highly relevant for the question. For example, [this code builds just fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3556e9846bb20adafa0b8b01dee0f41e).